# A student library program in Java

Tags: java, beginner

> A beginner level "Student Library Program" in Java, which interacts
>   the Students and the Books. This Library Program can do following
>   functions:
>
> 1. Adding a Book to Library.
> 2. Update Book Quantity.
> 3. Search a Book with its Serial number.
> 4. Search Books With Author Name.
> 5. Show all Books and their related Information.
> 6. Registering a Student.
> 7. Show All Registered Students.
> 8. Student can Check Out Book From Library (if registered).
>
>    - Student can not Check Out max than 3 Books
>    - You can only borrow a Book If it is Available in Library
> 9. Student can Check In Book to Library.
> 10. You can also see the Books which a Student has Checked Out(only while checking in)
>
> Note: At the time it can store only 50 books for simplicity in
>   program.

I have created this program to the best of my ability. I'm a beginner, so I couldn't do more.

```
package library;

import java.util.Scanner;



public class book {

public int sNo;
public String bookName;
public String authorName;
public int bookQty;
public int bookQtyCopy;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public book(){

    System.out.println("Enter Serial No of Book:");
    this.sNo = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Book Name:");
    this.bookName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Author Name:");
    this.authorName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Quantity of Books:");
    this.bookQty = input.nextInt();
    bookQtyCopy = this.bookQty;

}

}
```

---

```
package library;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class books {

book theBooks[] = new book[50];     // Array that stores 'book' Objects.
public static int count;    // Counter for No of book objects Added in Array.

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);




public int compareBookObjects(book b1, book b2){

    if (b1.bookName.equalsIgnoreCase(b2.bookName)){

        System.out.println("Book of this Name Already Exists.");
        return 0;

    }
    if (b1.sNo==b2.sNo){

        System.out.println("Book of this Serial No Already Exists.");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

public void addBook(book b){

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (this.compareBookObjects(b, this.theBooks[i]) == 0)
            return;

    }

    if (count<50){

        theBooks[count] = b;
        count++;

    }
    else{

        System.out.println("No Space to Add More Books.");

    }

}

public void searchBySno(){

    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tSEARCH BY SERIAL NUMBER\n");

    int sNo;
    System.out.println("Enter Serial No of Book:");
    sNo = input.nextInt();

    int flag = 0;
    System.out.println("S.No\t\tName\t\tAuthor\t\tAvailable Qty\t\tTotal Qty");
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (sNo == theBooks[i].sNo){

            System.out.println(theBooks[i].sNo + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookName + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].authorName + "\t\t" + 
                theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookQty);
            flag++;
            return;

        }

    }
    if (flag == 0)
        System.out.println("No Book for Serial No " + sNo + " Found.");

}

public void searchByAuthorName(){

    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tSEARCH BY AUTHOR'S NAME");
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Author Name:");
    String authorName = input.nextLine();
    int flag = 0;
    System.out.println("S.No\t\tName\t\tAuthor\t\tAvailable Qty\t\tTotal Qty");
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (authorName.equalsIgnoreCase(theBooks[i].authorName)){

            System.out.println(theBooks[i].sNo + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookName + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].authorName + "\t\t" + 
                theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookQty);
            flag++;
        }

    }
    if (flag == 0)
        System.out.println("No Books of " + authorName + " Found.");

}


public void showAllBooks(){

    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tSHOWING ALL BOOKS\n");
    System.out.println("S.No\t\tName\t\tAuthor\t\tAvailable Qty\t\tTotal Qty");
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        System.out.println(theBooks[i].sNo + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookName + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].authorName + "\t\t" + 
                theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookQty);


    }

}

public void upgradeBookQty(){

    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tUPGRADE QUANTITY OF A BOOK\n");
    System.out.println("Enter Serial No of Book");
    int sNo = input.nextInt();
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (sNo == theBooks[i].sNo){

            System.out.println("Enter No of Books to be Added:");
            int addingQty = input.nextInt();
            theBooks[i].bookQty += addingQty;
            theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy += addingQty;
            return;

        }

    }

}


public void dispMenu(){

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to Exit Application.");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to Add new Book.");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 to Upgrade Quantity of a Book.");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 to Search a Book.");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 to Show All Books.");
    System.out.println("Enter 5 to Register Student.");
    System.out.println("Enter 6 to Show All Registered Students.");
    System.out.println("Enter 7 to Check Out Book. ");
    System.out.println("Enter 8 to Check In Book");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------- 
   ---------------------------------------------");

}

public int isAvailable(int sNo){

    //returns the index number if available



    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (sNo == theBooks[i].sNo){
            if(theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy > 0){

                System.out.println("Book is Available.");
                return i;

            }
            System.out.println("Book is Unavailable");
            return -1;

        }

    }

    System.out.println("No Book of Serial Number " + " Available in Library.");
    return -1;


}

public book checkOutBook(){

    System.out.println("Enter Serial No of Book to be Checked Out.");
    int sNo = input.nextInt();

    int bookIndex =isAvailable(sNo);

    if (bookIndex!=-1){

        //int bookIndex = isAvailable(sNo);
        theBooks[bookIndex].bookQtyCopy--;

        return theBooks[bookIndex];
    }

    return null;

}

public void checkInBook(book b){

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (b.equals(theBooks[i]) ){

            theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy++;
            return;

        }

    }

}







 }
```

---

```
package library;

import java.util.Scanner;    
public class student {

String studentName;
String regNum;

book borrowedBooks[] = new book[3];
public int booksCount = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public student(){

    System.out.println("Enter Student Name:");
    this.studentName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Reg Number:");
    this.regNum = input.nextLine();

}
}
```

---

```
package library;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class students {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

student theStudents[] = new student[50];

//books book;


public static int count = 0;

public void addStudent(student s){

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if(s.regNum.equalsIgnoreCase(theStudents[i].regNum)){

            System.out.println("Student of Reg Num " + s.regNum + " is Already Registered.");
            return;
        }

    }

    if (count<=50){

        theStudents[count] = s;
        count++;

    }

}
public void showAllStudents(){

    System.out.println("Student Name\t\tReg Number");
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        System.out.println(theStudents[i].studentName + "\t\t" + theStudents[i].regNum);

    }


}

public int isStudent(){
    //return index number of student if available

     //System.out.println("Enter Student Name:");
    //String studentName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Reg Number:");
    String regNum = input.nextLine();

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (theStudents[i].regNum.equalsIgnoreCase(regNum)){

            return i;

        }

    }
    System.out.println("Student is not Registered.");
    System.out.println("Get Registered First.");


    return -1;

}
public void checkOutBook(books book){
    int studentIndex =this.isStudent();

    if (studentIndex!=-1){
        System.out.println("checking out");

        book.showAllBooks();//jjjjjjjjjjjj
        book b = book.checkOutBook();
        System.out.println("checking out");
        if (b!= null){

            if (theStudents[studentIndex].booksCount<=3){
                System.out.println("adding book");
                theStudents[studentIndex].borrowedBooks[theStudents[studentIndex].booksCount] = b;
                theStudents[studentIndex].booksCount++;
                return;

            }
            else {

                System.out.println("Student Can not Borrow more than 3 Books.");
                return;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Book is not Available.");

    }

}

public void checkInBook(books book){

    int studentIndex = this.isStudent();
    if (studentIndex != -1){
        System.out.println("S.No\t\t\tBook Name\t\t\tAuthor Name");
        student s = theStudents[studentIndex];
        for (int i=0; i<s.booksCount; i++){

            System.out.println(s.borrowedBooks[i].sNo+ "\t\t\t" + s.borrowedBooks[i].bookName + "\t\t\t"+
                    s.borrowedBooks[i].authorName);

        }
        System.out.println("Enter Serial Number of Book to be Checked In:");
        int sNo = input.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i<s.booksCount; i++){

            if (sNo == s.borrowedBooks[i].sNo){

                book.checkInBook(s.borrowedBooks[i]);
                s.borrowedBooks[i]=null;
                return;

            }


        }
        System.out.println("Book of Serial No "+sNo+"not Found");

    }



}


}
```

---

```
package library;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Library {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("********************Welcome to the Student Library!********************");
    System.out.println("              Please Select From The Following Options:               ");
System.out.println("**********************************************************************");
    books ob = new books();
    students obStudent = new students();
    int choice;
    int searchChoice;

    do{

        ob.dispMenu();
        choice = input.nextInt();

        switch(choice){

            case 1:
                book b = new book();
                ob.addBook(b);
                break;

            case 2:
                ob.upgradeBookQty();
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Enter 1 to Search with Serial No.");
                System.out.println("Enter 2 to Search with Author Name(Full Name).");
                searchChoice = input.nextInt();

                switch(searchChoice){

                    case 1:
                        ob.searchBySno();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ob.searchByAuthorName();

                }
                break;

            case 4:
                ob.showAllBooks();
                break;
            case 5:
                student s = new student();
                obStudent.addStudent(s);
                break;
            case 6:
                obStudent.showAllStudents();
                break;
            case 7:
                obStudent.checkOutBook(ob);
                break;
            case 8:
                obStudent.checkInBook(ob);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("CHOICE SHOULD BE BETWEEN 0 TO 8.");

        }

    }
    while (choice!=0);
































}

}
```

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, class names should begin with a capital letter.  So you should have

```
class Book { ... }
class Books { ... }
class Student { ... }
class Students { ... }
```

---

Each `book` has its own `Scanner`, as does `books`, every `student`, and `students`, and the `Library`.  This is *A Really Bad Idea*™.  A `Scanner` can buffer many, many characters that it has read from the underlying input stream but not presented to the caller.  Having more than one `Scanner` can lead to strange behaviour, where it looks like the input is getting lost, or arriving in the wrong order.  Having 103 scanners (one for each of the 50 `book` instances, one for each of the 50 `student` instances, plus one each for the `books`, `students`, and `Library` instances) will make scanner input issues virtually impossible to debug.

Create only one `Scanner`, in the `Library` class, and pass that instance to any method that needs to perform any reading.

---

## `book`

The `book` class is a data model.  It should just store information; it should not perform any I/O operations on the Console.  Doing so prevents it from being used in a GUI application.  If we remove the I/O, it could be used in a Console application or a GUI application without modification.  Here is the `Book` class without any I/O:

```
class Book {
    public int    sNo;
    public String bookName;
    public String authorName;
    public int    bookQty;
    public int    bookQtyCopy;

    public Book(int no, String title, String author, int quantity) {
        sNo         = no;
        bookName    = title;
        authorName  = author;
        bookQty     = quantity;
        bookQtyCopy = bookQty;
    }
 }
```

The creator of a `Book` would need to get the book information from the user (such as reading from the `Scanner`), and only call `new Book(...)` once it has all the data.

You haven't used `final` anywhere in your code.  If you have learnt it, consider that some of the `Book` fields should be `final` to prevent accidental changes.

You haven't used `private` anywhere in your code.  You may want to make some fields `private`, and provide getters (and setters), instead of allowing `public` access to the fields.

---

## `books`

```
public class books {
    book theBooks[] = new book[50];     // Array that stores 'book' Objects.
    public static int count;            // Counter for No of book objects Added in Array.
```

Why is `count` static?  If you have two `books` objects (say, two libraries -- one on campus, one downtown), each would have its own `theBooks` array for storing the `book` objects that it owns.  But there would only be one common `count` between the two.  They would be required to have the same number of `book` objects, but the `book` objects could be completely different?  That is seems like a design error.

`compareBookObjects()`: this function takes two books and returns ... what?  What does `0` mean?  What does `1` mean?  If `0` is returned, a message is written to the console, but what if we wanted to create a GUI program and there is no console???  It is only used by `addBook()`, so is more of a helper function, and perhaps should be `private`.  It is searching for a book title, and a book serial number.  You have other functions which search for books by title and serial number, and finding them is not an indication of a duplicate error, but of a successful search.  Maybe you need different helper functions, plural:

```
private Book findByTitle(String title) {
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        if (theBooks[I].bookName.equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
            return book;
        }
    }
    return null;  // Not found
}

private Book findBySerialNo(int no) { ... }
```

The you could re-write `addBook(...)` like:

```
public void addBook(book b) {
    if (findByTitle(b.bookName) != null) {
        System.out.println("Book of this Name Already Exists.");
    }
    if (findBySerialNo(b.sNo) != null) {
        System.out.println("Book of this Serial No Already Exists.");
    }
    if (count < 50) {
       theBooks[count] = b;
       count++;
    } else {
       System.out.println("No Space to Add More Books.");
    }
}
```

**Note**: Again, I/O in the `books` class should be eschewed.  `books` is another data model class, and shouldn't have any I/O.  So, perhaps the above checks can be moved out of `addBook` and to the caller which creates the `book`.  Then, the uniqueness of the book name / serial no can be tested even before creating the `book` object.

What is that magic number `50`?  Can we get rid of it?  Sure!

```
    if (count < theBooks.length) {
```

Now, if you change the allocation length of `theBooks`, you won't have to find all occurrences of that value in the source and change them.

The `flag` in `searchBySno()` is completely unnecessary.  If you find the book, you immediately return; the incremented `flag` value is unused.  If you don't find the book, you won't have returned, so the test `flag == 0` will always be `true`.  You can get rid of `flag`, and use the `findBySerialNo()` we created above:

```
...
Book book = findBySerialNo(sNo);
if (book != null) {
   // Print the book info
} else {
   System.out.println("No Book for Serial No " + sNo + " Found.");
}
```

Similarly, `upgradeBookQty()` can use `findBySerialNo()` to avoid writing the search for serial number loop yet again.

`dispMenu()` absolutely does not belong in `books`.  The menu is printed by a call in `Library`.  The input is asked for in `Library`.  The dispatch is done in `Library`.  The `dispMenu()` would make much more sense if move to `Library`.  Note that this is again moving I/O out of this data model.  (You might begin to think this is a common theme.)

`isAvailable()`, `checkOutBook()`, again is searching for a book by serial number.  Use the helper function.

---

## `student`

Similar comments as `book`.  Move I/O out of data model class.

---

## `students`

Similar comments as `books`.

- Move I/O out of data model
- `count` should not be `static`
- `50` should be `theStudents.length`
- Add a `findStudentByRegNum()` helper function, remove search loop from other methods.
- `3` should be `theStudents[studentIndex].borrowedBooks.length` ... wait ... what?

The `student` class should manage its own books!  Consider:

```
theStudents[studentIndex].borrowedBooks[theStudents[studentIndex].booksCount] = b;
```

You are referencing `theStudents[studentIndex]` twice in that statement, to get to the same `student` instance's `borrowedBooks` and `bookCount` fields.  Instead, imagine finding the student, and telling that student to add the book to its list.

```
student s = findStudentByRegNum(reg_num);
s.addBook(b);
```

And the student class would do:

```
borrowedBooks[ bookCount ] = b;
bookCount++;
```

As well as first checking whether it is allowed to borrow another book:

```
if (booksCount < borrowedBooks.length) { ... } else { ... }
```

**BUGS**

- Checking out the 4th book will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
- After a student has checked out 3 books, even after they have returned all 3 books, they can never check out another book, because `booksCounts` is never decremented.
- If a student tried to check out a book, and fails due to too many borrowed books, the book is lost (quantity has already been decremented in the library).

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. your answer is very helpful for me and really meant to me. you helped me alot in understanding these problems which i never considered tysm